# How to exclude jacoco from checks for classes that use gson's SerializedName?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

I have this class in my application written in kotlin:

```kotlin
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import java.util.Date

internal data class CloseLotDto(
    @SerializedName(value = "id") val closeLotId: String?,
    @SerializedName(value = "user_id") val userID: Long,
    @SerializedName(value = "address") val address: String,
    @SerializedName(value = "date_from") val dateFrom: Date,
    @SerializedName(value = "date_to") val dateTo: Date,
    @SerializedName(value = "point_of_interaction") val pointOfInteraction: PointOfInteractionDto,
    @SerializedName(value = "identification") val identification: String?,
    @SerializedName(value = "contents") val contents: List<SubContentDto>,
)
```

However, jacoco's coverage is accusing coverage failure in this class:
[image: jacoco kotlin coverage]

I would like to know if there is a way to make jacoco ignore gson's `@SerializedName` annotation so that test coverage is not harmed.

Comment: Why not excluding DTO/DTOs in general?